# Documentation for app update notification

Tags: ios, app-store, apple-push-notifications

Is there any documentation saying that when the application on Appstore is updated a push notification is send by Appstore itself to user about the update ?

Comment: I doubt there is any documentation regarding this as this is not true. Update push notifications, when seen, are initiated by the developer, not the App Store.

Comment: Thanks. but how to check if the app is updated in the code and provide the push notification?

Comment: If you're talking about your own application, then you are supposed to know when an update is available. If you're talking about an application that triggers alerts whenever ANY application has an update ready then I have no idea, though it sounds extremely complicated.

Comment: But i thought when i update the application on Appstore it shows a badge on the Appstore for available updates.

Comment: That's the operating system handling an internal notification, nothing you can intercept.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do that with [Search API](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html). In your app , after launching , check to see what is the latest version of your app on the AppStore. Like this:

```
- (void) checkForUpdates
{
    NSString *jsonUrl = @"http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=yourAppName&entity=software&limit=1";
    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:jsonUrl]];

    JSONDecoder *jsonKitDecoder = [JSONDecoder decoderWithParseOptions:JKParseOptionNone];
    NSObject *jsonObject = [jsonKitDecoder objectWithData:jsonData error:nil];
    int results = [[jsonObject valueForKey:@"resultCount"] intValue];

    if(results >0) // has results
    { 
        NSArray *results = [jsonObject valueForKey:@"results"];
        for(NSObject *aResult in results) 
        {
            NSString    *appStoreVersion = [aResult valueForKey:@"version"];
            NSString    *localVersion    = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];

            if(![appStoreVersion isEqualToString:localVersion])
            {
                 //there is an update available. Go crazy.
            }
        }
     }
}
```

I used JSONKit for this.. you can use any library that you like to parse the JSON retrieved by Apple.

Note: You can use this to notify the user that there is an update WHEN he opens the app. If you want something that tells the user as soon as the update is live , you need push notifications.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: how can I test this? please anyone?

Comment: @user1949873 : Set your app's version to 5.0 for example. And then replace 'yourAppName' with ...let's say 'Angry+Birds+Free'. This app currently has version 1.5.1. That is different than the value that you have set ( 5.0 ) so you will get inside that 'if' statement there. Hope this helps. Cheers!